# cant reset input in functional component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have a function component called TextInput and return an input element:

```
function TextInput({ type = "text", label, name, required = false }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.footerFormInput}>
      <input
        type={type}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name={name}
        required={required}
      />
      <label className={value && styles.filled} htmlFor={name}>
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i am trying to reset the form, but the value doesnt reset on Customized TextInput but yes on normal/original input element.

this is my page code:

```
const form = useRef();
  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputData = e.target.elements;
    if (inputData.from_email) {
      if (validator.isEmail(inputData.from_email.value)) {
        console.log("valid email");
      } else {
        // alert("Enter valid Email!");
        //email error..
        return;
      }
    }

    if (inputData.full_name) {
      if (
        validator.isAlpha(inputData.full_name.value, ["he"], {
          ignore: " ",
        }) ||
        validator.isAlpha(inputData.full_name.value, ["en-US"], {
          ignore: " ",
        })
      ) {
        console.log("valid name");
      } else {
        //name error
        return;
      }
    }
    if (inputData.phone && inputData.phone.value.trim() !== "") {
      if (validator.isMobilePhone(inputData.phone.value, ["he-US"])) {
        console.log("valid phone");
      } else {
        //phone error
        return;
      }
    }

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        process.env.EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
        process.env.EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
        form.current,
        process.env.EMAILJS_USER_ID
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          //do something with success
          ...
           form.current.reset(); //not working!!!!!!
        },
        (error) => {
          //do something with error
        }
      );
  };

  return (
...
<form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
                          <div className={styles.footerFormRow}>
                            <TextInput
                              type="input"
                              label='דוא"ל'
                              name="from_email"
                            />
                            <TextInput
                              type="input"
                              label="שם מלא"
                              name="full_name"
                            />
<input type="text" name="somename" />
                          </div>
</form>
...
)
```

only the somename input is reset, the others in the functional component no.
any hepl?

Comment: It sounds like you should be ["lifting state up"](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components) - have the state in the main component, and pass down handlers to the input components so they can update the state when they change.

Answer (score 0):

[HTMLFormElement.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) resets the values of the form elements to their "default values", but only if the form elements don't have a `value` defined, which will always "overrule" the `defaultValue`.

E.g. this unspecified `value` will be reset to the `defaultValue`:

```
<input type="text" defaultValue="initial value" />
```

But this  `value` won't be reset:

```
<input type="text" defaultValue="initial value" value="some value" />
```

This behavior is the same if the input elements are inside a child component:

```
const TextInput = function(){
    return <div>
        <input type={ 'text' } defaultValue={ 'changeable value' } /><br />
        <input type={ 'text' } value={'un-changeable value'} />
    </div>;
};

function App(){
    const formRef = React.useRef();

    const resetForm = function(){
        formRef.current.reset();
    };

    return <form ref={ formRef }>
        <input type={ 'text' } defaultValue={ 'input 1 initial value' } />
        <TextInput />
        <button onClick={ resetForm }>reset</button>
    </form>;
}
```

#### "Controlled input"

If an input element is a ["controlled input"](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable), then React sets (aka. "controls") the `value` property. You can only change it because the `onChange` handler
tells React to set `value` to a new value.

So `value` is specified at all times, and `form.reset()` can not reset `value` to `defaultValue`:

```
const TextInput = function( props ){
    const [ value, setValue ] = React.useState( 'controlled input' );

    function handleChange( event ){
        setValue( event.target.value );
    }

    return <div>
        <input type={ 'text' } defaultValue={ 'uncontrolled input' } /><br />
        <input type={ 'text' } value={ value } onChange={ handleChange } />
    </div>;
};
```

#### Solutions

You need to:

- either let the **form** handle the input values, so that the **form** can reset them
  (i.e. the inputs are not "controlled" by React),
- or let **React** handle the input values, and let **React** reset them
  (i.e. don't use `form.reset()` at all).

When working with React, you should usually let React control all the inputs.

There are different approaches for that. Here a quick example:

```
const TextInput = function( props ){
    const { value, onChange } = props;
    return <div>
        <input type={ 'text' } value={ value } onChange={ onChange } />
    </div>;
};

const initialFormValue = {
    title: 'title',
    firstName: 'first name',
    lastName: 'last name',
    email: 'my@email.com',
};

function App(){
    const [ formState, setFormState ] = React.useState( initialFormValue );

    const resetForm = function(){
        setFormState( initialFormValue );
    };

    const createChangeHandler = function( key ){
        return function( event ){
            setFormState({
                ...formState,
                [ key ]: event.target.value,
            });
        };
    };

    const onSubmit = function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    return <form onSubmit={ onSubmit }>
        <input type={ 'text' } value={ formState.title } onChange={ createChangeHandler('title') }/>
        <TextInput
            value={ formState.firstName }
            onChange={ createChangeHandler('firstName') }
        />
        <button onClick={ resetForm }>reset</button>
    </form>;
}
```